# How to generate table jasper with json array of subdataset

Tags: python, json, jasper-reports

I'm having problems to generate a table with all elements of json array.

JSON is that:

```
{
    "clasificacion_resultados":{
        "otras_empresas":[
            {
                "URL":"http://aa.com",
                "nombre_documento":"aa.pdf"
            },
            {
                "URL":"https://bb.pdf",
                "nombre_documento":"bb.pdf"
            },
            {
                "URL":"http://www.ccc.pdf",
                "nombre_documento":"ccc.pdf"
            },
            {
                "URL":"http://www.ddd.pdf",
                "nombre_documento":"www.ddd.pdf"
            },
            {
                "URL":"http://www.eee.pdf",
                "nombre_documento":"www.eee.pdf"
            },
            {
                "URL":"https://www.fff.pdf",
                "nombre_documento":"www.fff.pdf"
            },
            {
                "URL":"http://www.ggg.pdf",
                "nombre_documento":"www.ggg.pdf"
            }
          ]
    }
 }
```

And the following jrxml definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.6.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.6.0  -->
<jasperReport 
     xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 

     xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_Letter" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="792" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="0682e178-ad1a-4d9c-8c89-daa66551172a">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="json_data_results"/>
    <subDataset name="Dataset1" uuid="4cf6215f-dfdc-4280-8fe1-89e581f2783b">
        <field name="details_other_organizations" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[URL]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="details_other_organizations_2" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[nombre_documento]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString language="json">
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="URL" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[URL]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="nombre_documento" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[nombre_documento]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <detail>
        <band height="410" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="280" height="30" uuid="ad93247d-d7e3-45ff-841e-d9baf7682047"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{URL}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="280" y="30" width="280" height="30" uuid="07f04337-c4cb-4303-b348-1b035abf0add"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{nombre_documento}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="280" height="30" uuid="7ddb2dc9-394d-4cac-a91a-ce734012cf9a"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <text><![CDATA[URL]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="280" y="0" width="280" height="30" uuid="acc3ddf5-4f00-4703-9e8a-be61bdaf8fa4"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <text><![CDATA[Nombre documento]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

I'm using the library of python pyreportJaspert to generate a pdf from the json, using this function:

```
def json_to_pdf():
    input_file = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + \
             '/examples/json_results.jrxml'

    output = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '/output/_Result'
    json_query = 'clasificacion_resultados.otras_empresas'

    data_file = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + \
    '/examples/data.json'

    jasper = JasperPy()
        jasper.process(
        input_file,
        output_file=output,
        format_list=["pdf"],
        parameters={},
        db_connection={
            'data_file': data_file,
            'driver': 'json',
            'json_query': json_query,
        },
        locale='pt_BR'
    )

    print('Result is the file below.')
    print(output + '.pdf')
```

The execution of this python's function now generates one page per each element of json array instead of all elements in one page.

I would like to make a table to including all elements ("URL" and "nombre_document"). I do things that appear similar looking in stackoverflow but if I use a expression like that for the dataSet in a list

```
<datasetRun subDataset="listDataSet" uuid="71276e30-7777-44ae-b6d9-2087a4c51ca3">
   <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("Dataset1")]]></dataSourceExpression>
</datasetRun>`
```

The result of the function in python is `input file: "/home/xoan/Documentos/pyreportjasper/examples/Blank_Letter.jrxml" is not a valid jrxml file`

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

- If you really must use a table component you should set the following `dataSourceExpression` for your table's `datasetRun`:

  ```
  ((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("clasificacion_resultados.otras_empresas")
  ```

  and remove the fields and the associated textFields in the main dataset as they do not map to anything.
- But you might not need a table component after all. With your current JRXML:

  - remove the *Dataset1* `subDataset` to have a cleaner file
  - set the proper `queryString`:

    ```
    <queryString language="json">
        <![CDATA[clasificacion_resultados.otras_empresas]]>
    </queryString>
    ```
  - create a *Column Header* band
  - move the static text elements from the `detail` band to the `columnHeader` you've just created so that they don't repeat for each record
  - shrink the height of the detail band to wrap around the textField elements

The end JRXML for the non-table solution might look like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_Letter" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="792" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="0682e178-ad1a-4d9c-8c89-daa66551172a">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="json_data_results"/>
    <queryString language="json">
        <![CDATA[clasificacion_resultados.otras_empresas]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="URL" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[URL]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="nombre_documento" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[nombre_documento]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="30">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="280" y="0" width="280" height="30" uuid="acc3ddf5-4f00-4703-9e8a-be61bdaf8fa4"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <text><![CDATA[Nombre documento]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="280" height="30" uuid="7ddb2dc9-394d-4cac-a91a-ce734012cf9a"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <text><![CDATA[URL]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="280" height="30" uuid="ad93247d-d7e3-45ff-841e-d9baf7682047"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{URL}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="280" y="0" width="280" height="30" uuid="07f04337-c4cb-4303-b348-1b035abf0add"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{nombre_documento}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: I follow the second option and using function json_to_pdf() generates the same pdf, with one element ("URL" and "nombre_documento") per page.

It's necessary do anything else? Or change the definition of the python function, actually like I exposed in my question.

Comment: There is too much white space in your detail band. In Studio, double click under the textFields in order to shrink the band or set it manually. And move the static text elements in a `Column Header` band if you don't want them to be repeated.

Comment: The problem now is that if I don't use this arguments in python function json_to_pdf() :
db_connection={
            'data_file': data_file,
            'driver': 'json',
            'json_query': json_query,
        },

And I use the query that you say in studio, show only one page and value null.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include those extra steps. If you set up the JRXML template correctly and it works fine in Jaspersoft Studio then you can move to fix your Python code, if necessary.

Comment: In Jasper Studio show null values for the two fields, but using the the python function with the query argument generate a pdf with one pair of elements per page.

Comment: Added the resulting JRXML

Comment: I can't added because exced the characters, now is generating the pdf with all the elements in the same page, I follow the last step that you say, but the problem now is that I don't know the way of doing without stablish the query in the python function.

Comment: I uploaded the code jrxml to pastebin
https://pastebin.com/pb2UNtp3 , It's with other keys, because I'm using the original JSON that contains information for a project. But I repeat that now is generating a pdf with the elements in one page, I changed the height of the band

Comment: I don't know the `pyreportjasper` API. Maybe you could omit query in either python code or JRXML template. But it seems that you have achieved your goal, at least in terms of JasperReports template.